# Responsive image with %

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation and a `section-top` box which is `88%` high (no px value). How can I make my image responsive? When I look at the website on my mobile the image is half the page, I want it to be as high as the page.

```
#views_slideshow_cycle_teaser_section_home_view-block .views-field-field-home-image img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:-50px;
}
#section-top{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:88%;
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="section-top">
    <div id="featured">
        <?php print render($page['featured']);?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason I'm working with `height:88%` is because when I set a px value then it won't cover the page on a bigger resolution.

[Website](http://www.photo-cress.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `width:100;` and `height:100%` to the image, although that will break the image's aspect ratio. For the image to fill the maximum height without breaking the aspect ratio, you can do something like this:

```
width:auto;
height:100%;
max-width:100%;
*zoom:1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a **div** with **background-image** instead **img** or remove a fixed width and height of img.

Comment: The image is uploaded with CMS system so can't set it as background

Comment: A percentage instead of fixed values in `<img>` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#views_slideshow_cycle_div_home_view-block_0{
width:100%
}
```

and

```
views_slideshow_cycle_div_home_view-block_2{
width:100%
}
```